# accessing UI Thread with async / await with Mvvm

Tags: mvvm

I want to pass some contents on the DocumentViewer with progress indicator using Mvvm pattern, this generation will use UiElements after getting data from db asynchrounously.

```
    public async void ProcessReportAsync(){

        IsBusy = true;

        _reportDal = new ReportDal(_sprocName,_sprocParams);
        ReportContainers = new ObservableCollection<ReportContainerViewModel>();

        await Task.Run(() => _reportDal.InitReportDal());
        ReportDataTable = _reportDal.DataTableReport;

        await  Task.Run(() => ProcessedElements());

        var t3 = Task.Run(() => ProcessPage(_reportPage));
        var t4 = Task.Run(() => ProcessContainerData());
        await Task.WhenAll(t3, t4);
        var p = new PrinterViewModel(this);

      // This statement does'nt complete its execuation, which is adding more UIElements
        if(DispatcherHelper.UIDispatcher.CheckAccess()) {

            DispatcherHelper.UIDispatcher.Invoke(
                ()=>_document = p.CreateDocument(new Size(p.PrintDialog.PrintableAreaWidth,p.PrintDialog.PrintableAreaHeight))
                ,DispatcherPriority.Background);

        }
     // Can't reach this code
        IsBusy = false;


    }
```

Answer (score 1):

One nice aspect of `async`/`await` is that it takes care of dispatching back to the correct context for you.

```
public async Task ProcessReportAsync()
{
    IsBusy = true;

    _reportDal = new ReportDal(_sprocName,_sprocParams);
    ReportContainers = new ObservableCollection<ReportContainerViewModel>();

    await Task.Run(() => _reportDal.InitReportDal());
    ReportDataTable = _reportDal.DataTableReport;

    await Task.Run(() => ProcessedElements());

    var t3 = Task.Run(() => ProcessPage(_reportPage));
    var t4 = Task.Run(() => ProcessContainerData());
    await Task.WhenAll(t3, t4);
    var p = new PrinterViewModel(this);

    _document = p.CreateDocument(new Size(p.PrintDialog.PrintableAreaWidth,p.PrintDialog.PrintableAreaHeight));

    IsBusy = false;
}
```

I suggest you read my [`async`/`await` intro](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html) and my [MSDN article on `async`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx).

Comment: Thank you very much Stephen, contents for DocumentViewer is now show up. But the IsBusy prop is not working well and it seems that the Ui does'nt respond and run synchronously. I'll read your article.